# How to reverse order Stack and Queue in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue

I want to reverse the order of my output using stack and queues in Java.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Books {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> book = new LinkedList<String>();
        Stack<String> Title = new Stack<>();
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter four book titles.");
        int b = 4;
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
            System.out.print("Book " + i + ": ");
            String Enter = user.nextLine();
            book.offer(Enter);
        }

        System.out.println("New order of books:");
        System.out.println(book);

    }
}
```

Here is the output of this code.

```
Enter four book titles.
Book 1: wew1
Book 2: wew2
Book 3: wew3
Book 4: wew4
New order of books:
[wew1, wew2, wew3, wew4]
```

What I was trying to is to make it in reverse order. But I don't know what to do.

Comment: this question isn't related to stacks and queues I think. You can use simple arraylist for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the book in the `Queue` and add them to `Stack` then printing using `pop()` operation.

It's recommended to use `ArrayDeque` implementation when you want to use a `Stack`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter four book titles.");
        int b = 4;
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
            System.out.print("Book " + i + ": ");
            String Enter = user.nextLine();
            queue.add(Enter);
        }

        ArrayDeque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            stack.push(queue.poll());
        }

        System.out.println("New order of books:");
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(stack.pop()+" ");
        }
        user.close();
    }
```

---

, `output`

```
Enter four book titles.
Book 1: wew1
Book 2: wew2
Book 3: wew3
Book 4: wew4
New order of books:
wew4 wew3 wew2 wew1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the advantage that [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (double-ended queue). Note that `Deque` also implements [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) (single-ended queue).

You can use the method [`Deque#offerFirst(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#offerFirst-E-) to insert the book at the beginning of the queue. There is no need of reversing such queue afterward. Minimal example:

```
Deque<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    queue.offerFirst("book" + i);
}

System.out.println("Reversed order of books:");
System.out.println(queue);
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Reversed order of books:
> [book4, book3, book2, book1]
> ```

---

**Note 1:** Consider using [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) instad of [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) as long as you don't need to access by an index.

**Note 2:** Don't use `Stack` as long as it is considered [obsolete and deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-and-stack-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

Comment: The task that was given to use says "create a java stack consisting of (4) book titles. Pop all the elements one by one, each popped will be added to a queue". Is that even possible?

Comment: What you say right now is very different from what you describe in the question.

Comment: What do you mean? Its what it says in the instructions, we followed what was the instructions in the task but ended up a different expected output. The expected output was something reversed since the stack is getting pop one by one.

Comment: *" it says in the instructions"* - what instructions? There are no further instructios in the question. All the question states is *"I want to reverse the order of my output using stack and queues in java"*. There is no point in doint it in such way you describe unless it would be a school task as an exercise. In that case, you HAVE to provide such information or else don't expect such answer to appear.